# como paso dos fechas de angular 6 a php

Tags: php, angular

estoy intentando hacer una consulta de angular 6 a php de ventas entre fechas determinadas y no se como enviar desde el servicio dos fechas.Adjunto ambos códigos. Desde ya gracias .

Angular:

```
fecha(desde,hasta){
return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/sistemaKiosco/server/admiVentas/fecha.php?desde=${desde},hasta=${hasta}`);}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo saque lo dejo por si alguien le hace falta 
se debe usar el simbolo "&" sin las comillas quedaría algo así ;

fecha(desde,hasta){
return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/sistemaKiosco/server/admiVentas/fecha.php?desde=${desde}&hasta=${hasta}`);}

Answer (score 0):

Para poder enviarlo y ver tu respuesta debes de hacer el suscribe aquí te dejo un ejemplo

```
public fecha(desde:any,hasta:any){ 
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/sistemaKiosco/server/admiVentas/fecha.php?desde=`${desde}`&hasta=`${hasta}`")
    .map((data)=>{
      return data.json();
    }).subscribe((response)=>{
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```